# Gradle issue on Android Studio after upgrade from 0.3.2 to 0.3.4

Tags: android, gradle

After upgrade from Android Studio 0.3.2 to 0.3.4, I could not compile my project anymore due to a Gradle library issue

Error message was : `org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-rc-2.zip'.: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-rc-2.zip'.`

After trying various tips found on Internet, I just deleted all libraries containeing "1.9-rc2" from teh Adroid Studio `android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/` directory.

Close and reopen Android Studio and all fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying various tips found on Internet, I just deleted all libraries containeing "1.9-rc2" from teh Adroid Studio `android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/` directory.

Close and reopen Android Studio and all fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't installed yet, but Android Studio have just released 0.3.7, which claims to have solved a lot of gradle issues such as adding .jar libraries

http://tools.android.com/recent

Hopefully this will help you!